# How do I hold the value of a React Function Component even after it is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to hold the value of a React Function Component's location even after it is unmounted so that the value doesn't change once it is mounted again?

I am new to react. My question might sound simple.

I am sending some session values in the location the below React Function component `ConsolePage` from another Function Component. But when the `ConsolePage` gets unmounted and mounted again, the value that I had previously sent gets erased.

**Console Component**

```js
const ConsolePage: React.FC<ConsoleProps> = ({
  history,
  isAdmin
}) => {
  
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [isNewInitiative, setIsNewInitiative] = useState(false);
  const [successfulSubmitToast, setSuccessfulSubmitToast] = useState(false);
  const [displayedInitiatives, setDisplayedInitiatives] = useState<
    Initiative[]
  >([]);
  const [editInitiative, setEditInitiative] = useState<Initiative>();
  const [lastCategory, setLastCategory] = useState<string>("Environment");
  const location = useLocation(); //<----- This gets erased once the component is unmounted and mounted again 
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .}
```

This is how I send the location params from the `Login` Component:

```js
  history.push('/console',{
                                token:response.token,
                                companyID: response.user.companyID, 
                                firstName: response.user.firstName, 
                                lastName: response.user.lastName,
                                emailAddress: response.user.emailAddress 
                                }
                    );
```

I need the above params to stay in the ConsolePage component.

Comment: State that should be persisted between mounts and unmounts of a component should canonically be passed down (and up) as props or be stored in a more global state container (e.g. Redux).

Answer (score 1):

In React, data is "remembered" via something called *state*.  State is a per-Component concept - each component (or FunctionalComponent) has its own *state*.

So, how do you pass data from one Component to another? Props. But what if you want to change its value and send it back? You do **not** do so by changing the props value. Instead, you can send a function *along with* the props (as a separate prop). When the value is changed in the next component, you invoke this function, with the new data value as a parameter, and that function sends the data back to the parent component - until you reach the parent component where that data is stored in state (rather than being received as a prop value). It is there that you update the state in the usual manner (setState or useState).

But isn't there an easier way that doesn't involve batoning the data from component to component like a relay race? Yes - it's called "Context".

Context works like this. In a low-level component (usually your base component) you have some data stored in state. You then define a context to share that data, and then you surround your routes with the context ***Provider***.

Within each Component that is enclosed within the `MyContextName.Provider`, you then `useContext` within the component to read the context value and assign it to a local state variable.

Here are some articles with code demos and better explanations than I have provided above.

https://ui.dev/react-context/

https://blog.flexiple.com/provider-pattern-with-react-context-api/

https://www.cronj.com/blog/react-context